# Конструкция If else

Tags: c#, java, php, javascript, c++

Доброго времени суток, Хешкодовчане!)

Все мы знакомы с такой языковой конструкцией, как if else. Вот у меня возник такой вопрос. Возможно ли какими то способами так сказать "вломиться" не в свою часть данной конструкции?

Вот приведу пример (php):

```
$var = true;

if($var === true)
{
   //Вот сюда мы попадаем по логике
}
else
{
   //А сюда реально попасть, не изменяя значение переменной $var ?
}
```

Данный вопрос меня заинтересовал сегодня за обедом :) Буду рад выслушать Ваши мнения!

Comment:     goto :-)

Comment: Задачи как таковой нет. Просто хочу узнать о хитростях языков

Comment: goto есть для этого, для таких извращенцев и в php 5.2 добавили такую штуку

Comment: Оператор goto доступен в PHP начиная с версии 5.3

Answer (score 6):

Наверняка эту задачу можно решить без таких костыльных способов. Метки - это плохой стиль. Без них можно обойтись в 99% случаев. Тем более, что подобные вломы в чужие секции могут привести к очень неприятным последствиям, вплоть до краха скрипта! Вы лучше расскажите поподробнее о своей задаче, мы поможем решить =)

[image]

Comment: Задачи как таковой нет. Просто хочу узнать побольше о хитростях разных языков

Comment: @Demyan112rv, вот именно это - не "хитрость", это "костыльность", пахнущая самим ассемблером =)))

Comment: @SingleAsen Смех в том, что на практике (обычно в `C99`) все-таки есть пара кейсов, когда без `goto` можно обойтись, но его использование способствует *улучшению качества кода.*

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да, бывают такие ситуации( собственно, тот самый 1% ), когда надо выйти из вложенных друг в друга циклов или условий, например. В этом случае без прыжка не обойтись. Но как бы там ни было, это плохой стиль, он запутывает и вводит в заблуждение...

Comment: > когда надо выйти из вложенных друг в друга циклов или условий, например

есть еще адовые конструкции `break` и `continue`. Но бывает, что навешивать их друг на друга неудобно. К тому же можно делать `return` из середины ф-ции, но спорный вопрос ведет ли это к читаемости кода.

Comment: > когда надо выйти из вложенных друг в друга циклов

    while(true) {
        while(true) { 
            while(true) { 
                break 3; 
            } 
        } 
    }

Comment: Ну вот, тем более. Видите, goto - это уже скорее отпечаток бейсика...ныне и без goto вовсе можно обойтись.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, это в каком языке? В С и С++ так делать нельзя. Также нельзя в Java и Python

Comment: @mikillskegg, это PHP.

Answer (score 3):

**C, C++:**

1. goto
2. setjmp, longjmp
3. использование ассемблерных вставок с инструкциями перехода или колдовством над регистрами cs:ip :-)

Другой способ - срыв стека и корректировка адресов :-) Или любой другой способ редактирования кода программы на ходу :-)

Answer (score 1):

А разве то что вы хотите, это не:

```
$var = true;

if($var === true)
{
   foo();
}
bar();
```

Т.е. просто удаляем else и все.

Comment: Сама суть попасть в конструкцию else

Comment: Ты хочешь поломать логику?)) можно пойти влево, можно вправо, а ты хочешь идти влево и попасть вправо

Comment: Дадад) ...

Comment: ну тогда нужно переписать компилятор/интерпретатор.

Comment: можно через Define переопределить true и false, поменять местами)))))

Comment: Читерство!!! Вы еще if/else задефайните!!!!

Comment: А это реально?)